# Variable ndk.dir must not be added to local.properties

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a skeleton Android Studio project and am going through the following link to set it up for C++ compiling:

http://www.shaneenishry.com/blog/2014/08/17/ndk-with-android-studio/

The first step is to define `ndk.dir` in file `local.properties`.

However, the self-generated `local.properties` file has the following comments at the top:

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
```

Is there a different file to define `ndk.dir`? Regards.

Comment: http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/  alt way of doing that may be preferred by those using their own  android.mk

Answer (score 3):

I've got answer [here](http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/):

Just define `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` environment variable. It is also very useful for TeamCity job.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify that file just because it is generated from Android Studio preferences. Just use the related preferences directly in Android Studio, [as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159357/how-to-set-android-ndk-home-so-that-android-studio-does-not-ask-for-ndk-location)