# Gradle not finding updated NDK path & project directory

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, gradlew

I moved my Android `SDK` (and `NDK`) when my hard drive failed.

In my working project, I updated `local.properties` to reflect these changes in the variables `ndk.dir` and `sdk.dir`, yet when I run `./gradlew clean --info` on the command line from within my project directory, `gradle` gives me a failure at the following command:

```
<old_ndk_path>/ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=<oldprojdir>/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=<oldprojdir>/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=<oldprojdir>/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib clean
```

It's no wonder that the task fails, since no executable exists at that path now, but how can I get `gradle` to make use of the new `NDK` path? And how can I make it use the new project directory?

Comment: What OS are you using ? Take a quick look at this first (environmental variables)
NDK_HOME=C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle
NDK_MODULE_PATH=C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle
(are you using Android Studio ? if so put in the tag.. {command line only ?})..See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474050/android-studio-where-to-install-ndk-file-downloaded-it-in-zip/40475804#40475804

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39159450/5022983

Comment: @Sabish.M : Thanks. I tried that too, but to no effect.

Comment: @JonGoodwin : My OS is Linux. Looks like setting the env vars didn't get me what I needed, but deleting <projdir>/.gradle did.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `<projdir>/.gradle` directory and try again.